# CMSIS for NXP LPC1769

Tags: c, arm, lpc, cmsis

I downloaded the CMSIS version 3 and I have had some problems to use it. The main problem is in startup_device.s. I have no idea how to fulfill this file correctly and I couldn't find any good documentation. Has anyone tried to use this cmsis version? How to proceed? As I put in the title I'm using NXP LPC1769.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example startup file; either for CMSIS, or your NXP device?  Maybe both?  What have you tried?  Boot code is difficult to develop from scratch.  Do you have a scope or an on-board LED?

Comment: I've found a solution. I didn't know that I must to get the startup code from LPCXpresso.

Comment: It hasn't compability with cmsis 3.

Comment: You can post an answer of your solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is that LPCXpresso must to support the CMSIS version and it publics the CMSIS at its site. Them you can create your projetc based on it. Creating your project using LPC c project it automates the code and creates the correct startup_device.